# En un servidor apache2 no funciona la autenticación auth_digest., me sigue dejando acceder a la página sin pedirme autenticación

Tags: apache, auth

El modulo `auth_digest` está en `mods-enabled` y la consola me dice que está habilitado. He probado en la directiva `Directory` las rutas con comillas y sin comillas, o con `provider file` y sin el, y me sigue dejando entrar en la ruta especificada. Por supuesto, reinicio Apache después de cada cambio.
Uso Apache/2.4.41 en Ubuntu

El archivo `digest` está bien creado también, con la directiva `htdigest`

Adjunto código del archivo `conf` de mi sitio

Está igual que en todos los tutoriales pero no va, incluso reiniciando mi máquina virtual.

```
<Directory /www/dnoticias/public/private>
    Order deny,allow
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "diegolgroup"
    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/claves/claves_digest.txt 
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Comment: Algo en los logs de apache?

Comment: Creo que debe ser   <Directory "/www/dnoticias/public/private">

Comment: Intenta usando `<Location`, en lugar de `<Directory`

Comment: Gracias pero no ha valido

Comment: Gracias Duston pero ya lo probé con comillas y sin comillas. Lo único que he visto es que si cambio el nombre al index para que indexe los directorios no se ven dichas carpetas en la web, aunque en public si existen, y tengo la directiva Indexes activada en el sitio

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo y no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar.